# How does one do an else statement in Coq's functional programming language?

Tags: coq

I am trying to count the # of occurrences of an element `v` in a `natlist/bag` in Coq. I tried:

```
Fixpoint count (v:nat) (s:bag) : nat :=
  match s with
  | nil => 0
  | h :: tl => match h with
               | v => 1 + (count v tl)
               end
  end.
```

however my proof doesn't work:

```
Example test_count1:              count 1 [1;2;3;1;4;1] = 3.
Proof. simpl. reflexivity. Qed.
```

Why doesn't the first piece of code work? What is it doing when `v` isn't matched?

I also tried:

```
Fixpoint count (v:nat) (s:bag) : nat :=
  match s with
  | nil => 0
  | h :: tl => match h with
               | v => 1 + (count v tl)
               | _ => count v tl
               end
  end.
```

but that also gives an error in Coq and I can't even run it.

Functional programming is sort of new to me so I don't know how to actually express this in Coq. I really just want to say if `h` matches `v` then do a +1 and recurse else only recurse (i.e. add zero I guess).

Is there a simple way to express this in Coq's functional programming language?

The reason that I ask is because it feels to me that the match thing is very similar to an if else statement in "normal" Python programming. So either I am missing the point of functional programming or something. That is the main issue I am concerned I guess, implicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(this is similar to Daniel's answer, but I had already written most of it)

Your problem is that in this code:

```
match h with
| v => 1 + (count v tl)
end
```

matching with `v` binds a *new* variable `v`. To test if `h` is equal to `v`, you'll have to use some decision procedure for testing equality of natural numbers.

For example, you could use `Nat.eqb`, which takes two natural numbers and returns a `bool` indicating whether they're equal.

```
Require Import Nat.

Fixpoint count (v:nat) (s:bag) : nat :=
  match s with
  | nil => 0
  | h :: tl => if (eqb h v) then (1 + count v t1) else (count v t1)
  end.
```

Why can't we simply match on the term we want? Pattern matching always matches on constructors of the type. In this piece of code, the outer match statement matches with `nil` and `h :: t1` (which is a notation for `cons h t1` or something similar, depending on the precise definition of `bag`). In a match statement like

```
match n with
| 0 => (* something *)
| S n => (* something else *)
end.
```

we match on the constructors for `nat`: `0` and `S _`.

In your original code, you try to match on `v`, which isn't a constructor, so Coq simply binds a new variable and calls it `v`.

Comment: I think you guys are hinting that there is something wrong with me using `v` in the match part of my code but I false to understand what is wrong. Isn't that checking if `v` and `h` "match"? Or do I have a misunderstanding of what match means in Coq?

Comment: @Pinocchio Match is limited to examining how an element was constructed (e.g. is this natural number zero or a successor, is this list nil or a cons). It can't determine if two arbitrary terms are equal.

Comment: I am wondering if I would have noticed this if there was a natural way to insert print statements. Perhaps I should ask a different question about this, but how does one go about debugging Coq code like this one and examining what the thing is doing truly?

Comment: @Pinocchio I think the what you can do to test if something you wrote is correct is to 1. do some basic test cases (e.g. try `Compute count 1 [1,2,1,1,3]` and see if it's what you expect - as you understand better what's wrong, you can write better test cases) 2. try to prove a theorem about the behavior of the function and see what goes wrong. For this, you might try to prove that if `x <> y` (x != y), `count x (y :: s) = count x s`. You'll see that the left side simplifies to `S (count x s)`, which might be enough to see the error.

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful. Just out of curiosity (and learn Coqs functional programming better), there isn't a natural way to insert print statements like I'd do in Python?

Comment: @Pinocchio, I don't think so. If you're using tactics (like inside a `Proof...Qed` block), you can use `idtac` and it'll print out whatever argument you pass to it. But that won't work for just defining a Fixpoint like we're doing here. If anyone knows more, feel free to chime in.

Answer (score 2):

The `match` statement you tried to write actually just shadows the `v` variable with a new variable also called `v` which contains just a copy of `h`.

In order to test whether two natural numbers are equal, you can use `Nat.eqb` which returns a `bool` value which you can then match against:

```
Require Import Arith.

Fixpoint count (v:nat) (s:bag) : nat :=
  match s with
  | nil => 0
  | h :: tl => match Nat.eqb v h with
               | true => 1 + (count v tl)
               | false => count v tl
               end
  end.
```

As it happens, for matching of `bool` values with `true` or `false`, Coq also provides syntactic sugar in the form of a functional `if`/`else` construct (which is much like the ternary `?:` operator from C or C++ if you're familiar with either of those):

```
Require Import Arith.

Fixpoint count (v:nat) (s:bag) : nat :=
  match s with
  | nil => 0
  | h :: tl => if Nat.eqb v h then
                 1 + (count v tl)
               else
                 count v tl
  end.
```

(Actually, it happens that `if` works with any inductive type with exactly two constructors: then the first constructor goes to the `if` branch and the second constructor goes to the `else` branch.  However, the `list` type has `nil` as its first constructor and `cons` as its second constructor: so even though you could technically write an `if` statement taking in a `list` to test for emptiness or nonemptiness, it would end up reversed from the way you would probably expect it to work.)

In general, however, for a generic type there won't necessarily be a way to decide whether two members of that type are equal or not, as there was `Nat.eqb` in the case of `nat`.  Therefore, if you wanted to write a generalization of `count` which could work for more general types, you would have to take in an argument specifying the equality decision procedure.

Comment: I don't think I understand what your paragraph in parenthesis means. To me coming from Python, an if statement needs a boolean and depending on its value True or False it executes the first or the second statement. Not sure what constructors have to do with this.